# Why do I get a Type Error when mapping over JSON that is stored in React state?

Tags: json, reactjs, youtube-api

***update 2***

Trying to get the url of a video thumbnail from a request to the youtube api. The following code retrieves a playlist from youtube.

```
    import React from 'react';
    const playlist = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLdWBBPyLJJc2O6iRhPx-zGYfH33tPB7B4&key='
    const API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

    export default class Videos extends React.Component{

      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          videos: [],
          requesFailed: false
        }
      }

      componentDidMount() {

        fetch( playlist + API_KEY )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              videos: res.items
            })
          }, () => {
                this.setState({
                  requesFailed: true
                })
              }
          )
      }

      render() {

        const myVideos = this.state.videos.map(
          (item, index) => {
            console.log(item.snippet.thumbnails) 
            return(
              //    <img 
              //      key={index}
              //      src={item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}
              //      alt="video"
              //    />
              <p key={index}>video</p>
            )
          }
        )

        return(

          <section>
            {myVideos}
          </section>

        )

      }

    }
```

The result of console.log(item.snippet.thumbnails) looks like this:

[image: result]

So, to get the url of the thumbnail in high resolution, I do

```
console.log(item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url)
```

This indeed gives me the url but it also throws this error and breaks the app:

### TypeError: Cannot read property 'high' of undefined

Why?

Comment: pls post code samples

Comment: It looks like you are mapping over `this.state.video` and not `this.state.videos`

Missing an 's' character at the end.

Comment: sorry that was a typo in my shortened version of the code..corrected...The thing is, the console gives me the urls but also the error

Comment: That's simply not JSON what you have there. Please, first extract a [mcve] from your code before asking here.

Comment: Sorry for that. Maybe now @Ulrich Eckhardt

Comment: No. Please read that link and then ask yourself if your question contains all info that's required to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this

```
video.snippet.thumbnails && video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url
```

I can really only see your JSON and console statement in the question.

I want to assume there are some `snippet`s that do not have `thumbnails` and as a result, thumbnail is undefined sometimes (This throws an error and doesn't bother trying to render all others)

I am making an assumption that there's always a `snippet` in `item` here though

Alternately, you could have something like:

```
video.snippet.thumbnails ? video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url : 'default-url'
```

EDIT: 
Seeing the full question now, You would notice in your console results, that one of the values logged is `undefined` that's the cause of your issue

Comment: Thank you very much @delis ! I have to admit my problem was completely React related.  Always check if something exists before returning it! Albeit this code used to work in React 15 without errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your state to be null and a whole bunch of syntax errors etc... Try this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Videos extends React.Component {
  state = { videos: [], isLoading: true, error: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(playlist)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ videos: data.items, isLoading: false }))
      .catch(error =>
        this.setState({ error: error.message, isLoading: false }),
      );
  }

  renderVideos = () => {
    const { videos, isLoading, error } = this.state;
    if (isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    if (error) {
      return <div>{error}</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {videos.map(video => (
          <img src={video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url} alt="video" />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderVideos()}</div>;
  }
}
```